# What are the staking requirements to launch an airdrop?

Tags: staking, airdrops, price

Specifically an airdrop to all EOS holders based off the default eosio.token contract.

Comment: Please add more information, what are you trying to accomplish, is this based off the eosio.token contract?

Comment: Yes, based off the default token contract.

Answer (score 4):

### Update 4/2019:

You can use AirdropsDac vRAM enabled service:
https://airdropsdac.com/

Recently they launched the Emanate token with this setup:
https://medium.com/@airdropsdac/claim-your-emanate-emt-tokens-b24484e84a0e

vRAM provides a caching layer for the current RAM system.  It works much in the same sense as RAM and a DISK work on a normal PC.  RAM is scarce and used for instantly accessing data.  When it does not need to store that data, it uses disk instead.

vRAM works much in the same way allowing for data to be inserted into on-chain RAM when needed and evicted from RAM after used.  This process currently adds about a block time's worth of latency to the request.  The request must also be routed through a supported DSP.  More information can be found in the [whitepaper](https://liquidapps.io/):

---

If you [calculated](https://www.eosrp.io/#calc) based on current stats (4/18/19) and assumed you wanted to drop all in one day:

- Accounts: **940k** | https://eospark.com/
- RAM: **215mb** | 0.229kb / account
- CPU: **2219.4s** | 2.36ms / account
- NET: **120mb** | 128 bytes / account
- **~$5.50** / EOS

= **$82,450**

---

**Bottom line** (Previos Answer)

```
So if you are planning an Airdrop now, with the official genesis snapshot it would cost
around ~563 EOS, which right now translates to $6025.17 (USD) ~ leordev
```

Read the full article here: https://steemit.com/eos/@leordev/eos-ram-and-bandwith-analysis-airdropping-steps-on-junglenet

---

EOS NY Created a [Great Tool to calculate cost based on **CPU**, **NET**, and **RAM**](https://www.eosrp.io/)

**BP Name:** **eosnewyorkio** | [Source Code](https://github.com/eosnewyork/erp) | [Original Steem Proposal](https://steemit.com/eos/@eosnewyork/how-many-eos-tokens-do-i-need-for-my-dapp-the-eos-resource-planner)

---

**Please Up-Vote on Steemit! You may also vote him for moderator of the stackexchange**

[Accepting Nominations — Who should Moderate♦ this site?](https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site/22#22)

[image]

[image][image]

---

**Other Contributors:**

**@[nsjames](https://steemit.com/@nsjames)** | [Scatter EOS Wallet Creator](https://get-scatter.com) & [BP Portal Contributor](https://eosportal.io)

**@[syedjafri](https://steemit.com/@syedjafri)** | [EOS Cafe](http://eoscafecalgary.com) | BP Name : **eoscafeblock**

**@[blockliberty](https://steemit.com/@blockliberty)** | [EOS LibertyBlock](https://libertyblock.io/) | BP Name : **libertyblock**

**@[cryptolions](https://steemit.com/@cryptolions)** | [Creaters of the Jungle  Testnet](http://dev.cryptolions.io) | BP Name : **cryptolions1**

---

[image]

Comment: I’ve just edited the question. I was asking from a dapp developer’s point of view, roughly how much EOS needs to be staked to distribute the tokens. There’s hardly any documentation on this or any clear cost/ benefit analysis.

Comment: I elaborated...

Comment: @Nat what do you mean by "claiming" an airdrop token.  If you were to create a token on the standard `eosio.token` contract then the issuer would have to pay for the RAM storage for every account it sends tokens to, correct?  Are you saying that we would need to create another contract just for the new token, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the `eosio.token` contract if everyone had to re-write their own?  I can't find any detailed information on how airdrops work and how EOS members are expecting to receive them.

Comment: A man smarter than I elaborates on this topic here: https://steemit.com/eos/@leordev/eos-ram-and-bandwith-analysis-airdropping-steps-on-junglenet

Comment: @MagicManXpress I was already building something to claim tokens but looks like from Dan's comment something is going on... I just hold it while I wait for his answer -- Thanks for the recommendation folks! :)